# Change the color of a item if it has been edited

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a SharePoint list created and would like the item "Did Operations Respond?" to change color depending on if another field "Ops Response" has been edited in that same row.

I cant figure out how to do it. I can change the color manually but the chances of my ops team doing that if they go to respond is slim to none. And would like to automatically do it if they were to just respond in the "Ops Response" field.

[image: Picture of my SharePoint list]

Comment: What type of column is your `ops response`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a JSON column format can use the value from another column to conditionally color the current column, including checking against the modified and created dates to see if it has been updated since it was created, there is no way for the formatter to tell what field was modified.

But if you could potentially set up a Flow in Power Automate to do this.  If you create a Flow that is triggered by item being updated, then in the Flow check to see if your `Ops Response` field has changed, and if so, then have the Flow update the `Has Responded` field to the appropriate color.

Comment: Thanks! This works!